# cross domain request data using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am trying to access an external url which returns json data and based on one of the value in that data I need to hide a table row. I have tried several options to do this with jsonp, jquery and ajax but nothing seem to work. YQL is working for me but I can't use outer Service as the code need to be independent. Please someone let me know how I can make this work with javascript

This is one approach I have tried

```
<script type='text/javascript'>



    function checkBlueLight() {

        $('#trBlueLight').hide();

        $.getJSON('http://.../Lights/getBlueLight?callback=?', function (data) {
            if (data.expDate != null) {
                $('#trBlueLight').show();
            } else {
                $('#trBlueLight').hide();
            }
        });
        }



    </script>
```

This is another approach I have tried. same issue unauthorized - 401

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://.../Lights/getBlueLight',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       if (data.expDate != null) {
           $('#trBlueLight').show();
       } else {
           $('#trBlueLight').hide();
       }
    }
});
```

I have even tried to get data from url using jsp with  and that also causing some permission issue

Comment: What is the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried combination of jquery-JSONP with callback and Ajax-Json combination

Comment: Can you paste you code here?

Comment: I am adding it to my quesiton on top. please look

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the external url?  Because you can do:

On your local page:

```
function your_function(data) {
        alert(data.message)
}
```

And then on http://www.include.me/remote.php (or whatever is returning JSON) you would have it return

```
your_function({message: "it works!"});
```

And then back on your local page:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "http://www.include.me/remote.php");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Which will then include the script, which simply tells it to run your already defined function with the data it provides.

Comment: I can't control external url

Answer (score 0):

If you can't control the external URL, and it doesn't support `CORS` nor `JSONP`, then you best option is to write a server side proxy method for the service. So on your server, you expose a new endpoint on your own host that on the server side access the real service on your clients behalf, and returns the result to your client.

Answer (score 0):

For using jsonp, the server should bind the return type with a callback function. If it not, you cannot get the data from server.

If you are using cors, server should support that. Which means server should set,

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to "*"
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue with JS or jQuery is that crossdomain data  may not be possible depending on the browser or server or a combination of both that prohibits the data exchange. This is security policy on many browsers and servers.

The best and safest choice is using a combination of JS or jQuery (Ajax call) with PHP cURL where the cURL will make the call requesting the data xml/json format and then sent back to the Ajax request.

Please take a look at the following example:

In the JS/JQuery AJax script:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: 'php_script_with_cURL.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:'THE_DATA_OR_REQUEST',  
      type:'post',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.expDate != null) {
          $('#trBlueLight').show();
        } else {
          $('#trBlueLight').hide();
        }
      }
   });
```

and then in the php file (must be in the same server as your JS):
(you can use url string or post to request the data)

```
    //USE POST IF YOU NEED TO SEND VARIOUS COMMANDS TO GET THE DATA BACK
    $post = $_POST;

    //INIT THE CURL CALL
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,

        //this will tell the server how to return the data format
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),

        //use the query string if require, if not just remove it
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://THE_URL_HERE.COM?request_value=some_value',

        //use the post only if yo need to post values 
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            value1 => $post['value1'],
            value2 => $post['value2']
        )
        //alternative you can also pass the whole POST array
        //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post
    ));

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    if(!$data){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    } 

    curl_close($curl);

    //echo the data that will be sent to the JS/JQuery Ajax call
    echo $data;

    //or if you need to do more processing with php  
    //$response = json_decode($data);
```

Hope this helps :)
Happy coding !

Comment: We use JSP and not PHP so if you have something with jsp please let me know

Comment: I dont know/use JSP, but I think this article explains everything to do with JSP and AJAX . http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples

Comment: The question asked for pure JS